# Accessing item in list of lists using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, list

How do I access an item in a list of lists in GEE?

I know that using the method get() returns the element at the specified position in list. But the result of list.get(0) is [1, 2, 3], and I want the first element of each list in the list.

```
var list = ee.List([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 5]
]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually when you want to do something with each item in a list, you use `map`. In this case since you want the first element, you put `.get(0)` inside the `map` function.

```js
var list = ee.List([[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]]);

print(list.map(function (innerList) {
  return ee.List(innerList).get(0);
}));

// Prints: [1,10,100]
```

This example contains `ee.List(innerList).get(0)` instead of `innerList.get(0)` because the `map` doesn't know that every element of `list` is a list — this cast is necessary in most cases when you `map` over a list to specify the expected type so you can call `.get` or other specific method on it.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin for your help. I'm trying to calculate precipitation accumulation. I have created a function whose entry is a list of lists that contain the year, start_day and end_day. To apply this function over the list, I used .map as you comment before. But I am finding different errors: The first one is .map is not a function and when I try to fix it I find another error of Invalid type. This is the link to my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7460981e0f6e7c99e4c36f0507383cfa Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @NataliaQuintero As I wrote in my answer, you must use `ee.List` to cast the element inside of the mapping function. In that case, you can do it by adding `list_of_sequence = ee.List(list_of_sequence);` as the first line of the function `cumPr_of_each_year`.